# Can I use domain only for registering a redirect url for OAuth2 with Google API

Tags: rest, redirect, google-api, oauth-2.0

I'm using OAuth2 for retrieving contacts from a Facebook, Windows Live and Google.
The website I'm working on follows a RESTful approach with the users username in the URL.  The redirect url I was planning to use followed this same pattern but I've run into a problem.

Whereas Facebook and Windows Live allow you to register an authorized domain to redirect back to, Google API console seems to require a specific URL.  Obviously it is not possible to register every users URL so is there a way round this such as using wildcards?

Comment: This is not the case with Google. What have you tried (if you can remove the private part)? The Authorized Javascript Origin must be the host, and you may use any URLs which are paths from this origin.